# cannot invoke tomcat manager:network unreachable

Tags: maven-tomcat-plugin

i am using maven to deploy in tomcat 6

url is http://localhst:8080/manager
the error is shown below i ma usisng eclipse

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project strutsandhibernte: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Network is unreachable: connect ->    [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Is it `http://localhst:8080/manager` or `http://localhost:8080/manager ` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/html
```